# Cannot extract values from a map in apache pig

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig

I have a simple relation, `v`, in Apache Pig:

```
dump v;

(151364,[ 'ref'#'R813','highway'#'secondary', 'name:ga'#'Lána Chairdif', 'name'#'Cardiff Lane'],(31015271, 31053762))
(151368,[ 'ref'#'N1', 'oneway'#'yes','designation'#'Buses Only', 'highway'#'trunk', 'motor_vehicle'#'designated', 'name:ga'#'Cearnóg Pharnell Thoir', 'maxspeed'#'30', 'name'#'Parnell Square East'],(389365, 540403072))
(151596,[ 'name:en'#'Liffey', 'boundary'#'administrative', 'name:ga'#'An Life','admin_level'#'8', 'name'#'Liffey', 'waterway'#'river'],(1347749, 1426049020, 1347745, 1426049019, 1347742, 900075612))
(367947,[ 'maxspeed'#'80', 'ref'#'L2223','highway'#'tertiary'],(13259933, 2384217, 335978958))
(367952,['created_by'#'YahooApplet 1.0', 'name'#'Charnwood Avenue', 'highway'#'residential'],(2384386, 25963471, 14949594, 2384385, 6146344, 2384254))
(508603,[ 'ref'#'L3018','highway'#'tertiary', 'maxspeed'#'50', 'name'#'Shelerin Road'],(2854184, 2854168, 335978984, 2853307, 2384254, 335978978, 335978975, 2655735, 2655703, 392675957, 11676198, 920037194, 244531387, 2655952, 11675077))
(727153,[ 'ref'#'N8','highway'#'trunk', 'name'#'Merchants' Quay'],(354153, 453344873))
(727157,['highway'#'unclassified', 'oneway'#'yes', 'maxspeed'#'30', 'name'#'Kyle Street'],(354168, 354167))
(727159,['highway'#'unclassified', 'oneway'#'yes', 'maxspeed'#'30', 'name'#'North Main Street'],(354178, 465226768, 354167, 413995429, 72219131, 685537307, 1232381779, 354164))
(727161,[ 'maxspeed'#'30','highway'#'pedestrian', 'name'#'Maylor Street'],(1486492976, 1515360721, 1515360722, 1515345383, 1515344226, 1515344227, 1515344228, 1515344231))
```

On @orangeoctopus's advice, I have tried regenerating my data with any `'` in the key names, and I have this data:

```
(151364,[ ref#'R813', name:ga#'Lána Chairdif', name#'Cardiff Lane',highway#'secondary'],(31015271, 31053762))
(151368,[ motor_vehicle#'designated', name#'Parnell Square East', highway#'trunk', oneway#'yes',designation#'Buses Only', maxspeed#'30', name:ga#'Cearnóg Pharnell Thoir', ref#'N1'],(389365, 540403072))
(151596,[ name:en#'Liffey', boundary#'administrative', waterway#'river', name:ga#'An Life',admin_level#'8', name#'Liffey'],(1347749, 1426049020, 1347745, 1426049019, 1347742, 900075612))
(367947,[highway#'tertiary', maxspeed#'80', ref#'L2223'],(13259933, 2384217, 335978958))
(367952,[ name#'Charnwood Avenue',created_by#'YahooApplet 1.0', highway#'residential'],(2384386, 25963471, 14949594, 2384385, 6146344, 2384254))
(508603,[ maxspeed#'50', ref#'L3018', name#'Shelerin Road',highway#'tertiary'],(2854184, 2854168, 335978984, 2853307, 2384254, 335978978, 335978975, 2655735, 2655703, 392675957, 11676198, 920037194, 244531387, 2655952, 11675077))
(727153,[highway#'trunk', name#'Merchants' Quay', ref#'N8'],(354153, 453344873))
(727157,[ oneway#'yes', maxspeed#'30', name#'Kyle Street',highway#'unclassified'],(354168, 354167))
(727159,[ oneway#'yes', maxspeed#'30', name#'North Main Street',highway#'unclassified' (354178, 465226768, 354167, 413995429, 72219131, 685537307, 1232381779, 354164))
(727161,[highway#'pedestrian', name#'Maylor Street', maxspeed#'30'],(1486492976, 1515360721, 1515360722, 1515345383, 1515344226, 1515344227, 1515344228, 1515344231))
```

In both cases v has the same schema/structure:

```
grunt> describe v;
2012-01-09 22:55:34,271 [main] WARN  org.apache.pig.PigServer - Encountered Warning IMPLICIT_CAST_TO_CHARARRAY 1 time(s).
v: {id: int,tags: map[ ],nodes: (null)}
```

Then I try to extract out just one value from the `tags` map:

```
grunt> w = foreach v generate tags#'ref';    
dump w;
```

But it only gives me empty data, even though some elements have data here.

```
()
()
()
()
()
()
()
()
()
()
```

With the old 'quoted' keys I tried (as per @orangeoctopus' solution)

```
w = foreach v generate tags#'\'ref\'';
```

And that gave me the same 'empty' data, and didn't work. (I also tried other combinations of `'` and `"`, like `"'ref'"`/`'"ref"'`/etc. but all except `'\'ref\''` were invalid pig latin syntax)

What's going on? If i try to filter based on the tag value, (e.g. `filter v by tags#'highway' != ''`), I get nothing, which is consistant with this above problem of not being able to extract data from the map, am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Very tricky!

Your problem is that your literal data includes single quotes. Your string is not `ref` (3 characters long), it is `'ref'` (5 characters long). I realized this because the dump of a map containing strings does not typically have the quotes there.

Therefore, you need to be keying including those quotes (you have to escape them with `\`):

```
grunt> w = foreach v generate tags#'\'ref\'';
```

Your other option would be to change the way your data is being loaded so it doesn't include the single quotes in the strings themselves, and strips them out. `PigStorage` doesn't do this for free, but you could use something like [`REPLACE`](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.9.1/func.html#replace) or your own UDF to do this.

Comment: Good idea! However I tried your quoting and it didn't work. I then regenerated my data without any 's in the keys and it still didn't work (question updated). Any ideas?

Comment: Can you show your entire pig script? And perhaps paste a few lines of the raw data.

Answer (score 3):

Are you loading the data correctly too? It is weird that there is a space after the [ and before the ] when you dump your map.

Also it is more simple to drop all the quotes in the key and value in the [input data](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.9.1/basic.html#Example-N107B7). For example:

Input file

```
151364  [ref#R813,highway#secondary]
```

Pig

```
a = LOAD 'data.txt' AS (id:INT, m:MAP[]);
DUMP a;
b = FOREACH a GENERATE m#'ref';
DUMP b;
```

Output

```
(151364,[highway#secondary,ref#R813])

(R813)
```

Comment: I am creating the text with a script, and there are 3 types of input line (based on the first element), so each line doesn't always have the same schema, so I can't do a 'LOAD ... AS ....'.